# Where does MacOS Audio MID Setup save the aggregated devices configuration file?

Tags: macos, aggregate, core-audio

I have tried to trace to open files via Activity Monitor-> Open Files and Ports with no luck.
I am trying to get information on how aggregate device configurations are described.
Another option is to find a decent documentation that describes how to create an aggregated device programmatically and all the available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create aggregate devices programmatically you can use the methods provided by the CoreAudio framework.

To be more specific, in `AudioHardware.h` you'll find the methods `AudioHardwareCreateAggregateDevice` and `AudioHardwareDestroyAggregateDevice` which enable you to create and destroy aggregate devices.

Along with a description (`CFDictionaryRef`) filled with constants from under the 'AudioAggregateDevice Constants' section in AudioHardware.h you can decide how to configure the aggregate setup.

Please note that the [online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/1422096-audiohardwarecreateaggregatedevi) of these methods doesn't give you what you need. You really have to dive into the raw header, which is very readable anyway.

For an example on how to create an aggregate device you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60445512/2576876).

Finding and using config (state) files of `coreaudiod` directly will most likely lead you into trouble, and there is a high chance of breaking your code at every macOS update.